# Funky text encoding in CSV

Tags: string, csv, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I'm working on concatenating the monthly CSVs from the FAA's [on-time performance dataset](https://www.transtats.bts.gov/Tables.asp?DB_ID=120&DB_Name=Airline%20On-Time%20Performance%20Data&DB_Short_Name=On-Time) into one big flat file with consistent formatting.

Twelve months of this data (2001-02 to 2002-02) has weirdly garbled values for the Tail Number field. For example:

- N299US becomes N299äâ
- N728UW becomes N728Ræ
- N615MQ becomes -N615M

These values are encoded in ISO 8859-1 (it's invalid utf8). I found the unscrambled values by searching for unique matches for the "N###" part of the tail number in the next good month's dataset (tail numbers are registration numbers for planes, and don't change month-to-month, so I feel reasonably confident about this).

I can't figure out whether this is some funky text encoding scheme I haven't seen before that I could convert back into UTF8 - or if there was some bug in the code the FAA uses to compile the CSVs, and this data is just garbage.

Any help figuring this out would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Very strange.. and there seems to be no logic in the ascii values (except for most of them you could subtract 143, but then you also have @@@, é, the leading -, etc..) Downloading a single column or region doesn't help. So I think you'll have to contact the site owner and ask for a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the US Office of Airline Information. Evidently, whatever happened to the data is lossy, and there's no way to recover the correct tail numbers.